# show and hide element after executing a function

Tags: angularjs

> I need when a user logged In my system log out button appear and when logged
>   out the button disappear to implement I'd first try it by button click following
>   code:

```js
$scope.test = function () {

        if ($rootScope.authenticated) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        } else {

            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
        }
    }
```

```html
<li class="dropdown" id="profile-messages" ng-class="authenticated ? 'show' : 'hide' " @*ng-show="authenticated"*@>
                <a title="" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#profile-messages" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="icon icon-user"></i>
                    <span class="text" ng-model="username">{{username}}</span>
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> {{user.authenticated}}</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-check"></i> My Tasks</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#" ng-show="user.authenticated" ng-click="logout()"><i class="icon-key"></i> خروچ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
<li class=""><a title="" href="#" ng-click="logout()" ng-show="authenticated"><i class="icon icon-share-alt"></i> <span class="text">Logout</span></a></li>

<input type="button" id="test" value="test" ng-click="test()" />
```

and when click on button every thing worked fine but when done same way in my log in function it not worked im using following code

```js
    $scope.login = function () {
        var hasError = false;
        if (!hasError) {
            if (!$rootScope.authenticated) {
                var result = LoginFactory.adminLogin($scope.loginForm);
                result.then(function (result) {
                    if (!result.ok) {
                        toastr.warning(result.Message, 'اخطار', { timeOut: 7000 });
                    } else {
                        $location.path(result.url);
                        $rootScope.authenticated = result.authenticated;
                        $rootScope.username = result.user;
                        
                       
                    }
                })
            } else {
                toastr.error("you are already logged In!", '', { timeOut: 0 });
            }
        }
```

> and my service is:

```js
adminLogin: function (model) {

            var deferredObject = $q.defer();
            $http.post('/Core/User/LoginApp', { model: model }).success(function (data) {

                if (!data.Ok) {
                    deferredObject.resolve({ ok: false, Message: data.Message });
                } else {
                    deferredObject.resolve({ ok: true, url: data.Url, user: data.User, authenticated: data.authenticated });
                }
            }).error(function () {
                deferredObject.resolve({ success: false, Message: data.Message });
            });
            return deferredObject.promise;
        }
```

how can I solve this problem

Comment: what display `result.authenticated;`? and try it with `result.data.authenticated;`

Comment: response of ngular Post requst  i'd edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Use double negation to make it `boolean`.

```
$rootScope.authenticated = !! result.authenticated;
```